# Django.models custom blank value

Tags: django, python-3.10

thanks for tanking the time to look at this query.

I'm setting an ID field within one of my Django models. This is a CharField and looks like the following:

```
my_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5,
                           validators=[RegexValidator(
                               regex=ID_REGEX,
                               message=ID_ERR_MSG,
                               code=ID_ERR_CODE
                           )])
```

I would like to add a default/blank or null option that calls a global or class function that will cycle through the existing IDs, find the first one that doesn't exist and assign it as the next user ID. However, when I add the call `blank=foo()` I get an error code that the function doesn't exist.

Best,
pb

**Edit1**: I also tried using a separate utils file and importing the function, but (unsurprisingly) I get a circular import error as I need the call the class to get the objects.

**Edit2 (Reply to Eugene)**: Tried that, solved the circular import but I'm getting the following error:

```
    TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Previously my override of the save function worked perfectly:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(Staff, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The custom id function:

```
def get_id_default():

    from .models import MyObj
    for temp_id in range(10_000, 100_000):
        try:
            MyObj.objects.get(my_id=str(temp_id))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            break  # Id doesn't exist

    return str(hive_id)
```

**Edit 3 (Reply to PersonPr7):** Unfortunately, the kwargs doesn't seem to have my id in it. Actually, after having a print the kwargs dictionary comes back empty.

Save function:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        print(kwargs) #  --> Returns {}
        if kwargs["my_id"] is None:
            kwargs["my_id"] = self.get_id_default()

        self.full_clean()
        super(Staff, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Where the get_id_default is a class function:

```
    def get_id_default(self):
        for temp_id in range(10_000, 100000):
            try:
                self.objects.get(my_id=str(temp_id))
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                break  # Id doesn't exist

        return str(temp_id)
```

**Solution1:**

For those who are may be struggling with this in the future:

Create a utils/script .py file (or whatever you wanna call it) and create your custom script inside.

```
from .models import MyModel

def my_custom_default:
    # your custom code
    return your_value

Inside the main.models.py file. 

from django.db import models
from .my_utils import my_custom_default

class MyModel(model.Model):
    my_field = models.SomeField(..., default=my_custom_default)
```

**Solution2:** Create a static function within your Model class that will create your default value.

```
@staticmethod
def get_my_default():
    # your logic
    return your_value
    # NOTE: Initially I had the function use self
    # to retrieve the objects (self.objects.get(...)) 
    # However, this raised an exception: AttributeError: 
    # Manager isn't accessible via Sites instances
```

When setting up your model give your field some kind of default i.e. `default=None`

Additionally, you need to override the models save function like so:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.your_field is None:
        self.my_field = self.get_my_default()
    
    self.full_clean()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: try providing default as callable/function, like `default=foo` (without parenthesis)

Comment: Hi Eugene, I tried that still doesn't work. "name foo doesn't exist"

Comment: Obviously you need to define the foo function that should perform the lookup. Try putting it to separate module and to avoid circular import put  import of the model to the **body** of the foo function.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the reply. Please see **Edit 2**. Unfortunately I'm getting an error when I override the save function. I need the save function overridden or my custom regex validation doesn't return an Exception when an input is incorrect.

Comment: checking `get_id_default` function from your question and I think it is not the way to go. Imagine that 99K of IDs already exists - the function would make 99K db queries only to find ID 99001. This is a waste of resources. Can you describe the problem you are trying to solve with your function? Would it suffice if db would autoincrement `my_id` value for you, starting from some big value that for sure does not exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250145/discussion-between-pb-and-eugene-prikazchikov).

Comment: You are definitely correct, super inefficient and a huge waste of resources. Wanted to get the basic concept working first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the Model's save method and performing the logic there:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #Custom logic
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Edit:
You don't need to use **kwargs.
You can access your whole model from the save method and loop over objects / ids.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, please see **Edit3**.  Unfortunately the kwargs dict is empty. Any ideas?